# How to monitor audio output route changes in iOS7 ([AVAudioSession sharedInstance].currentRoute)

Tags: ios, audio, key-value-observing

We're using key-value observing to see if audio output route is changed with the following code:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentRoute" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
```

However, it doesn't work when I plug/unplug headphones. I can monitor "outputvolume" changes with the same api.

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(currentRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do you listen to `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNofication`?

Comment: @Phil `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(currentRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];`